# Google Conversion Code HTML5

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Google Adword Conversion code create one image with width="1" and height="1" they make a big white line my HTML.

What should I do?

They create image like

my Code is HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Set display to none in your style sheet

Comment: That makes no sense. It's just a tracking pixel, it still loads, it just doesn't show up on the page. If you really care about that then set the position to absolute and move it up 1px and to the left 1px